# enzyme is not reading prop on shallow method

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

enzyme is not reading the prop `image_url` within the shallow method. But it seems to read the 'src' property.

**Image.test.js**

```
  it('should test for image_url prop', () => {
        const url = 'https://res.cloudinary.com/dq281hpqd/image/upload/v1559697741/s3wxjfweznq8kqum2p0x.png';
        const wrapper = shallow(<Image image_url={url}/>)
        wrapper.setProps({ image_url: url });

        // expect(wrapper.prop("src")).toBe(url) // this passes but not the way it should be

        // it should check for image_url prop, but the following code is not working

        expect(wrapper.prop('image_url')).toBe(url);
    })
```

**Image.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Image = (props) => (
    <img width="100%" height="100%" alt="stuff" src = {props.image_url} />
)

export default Image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
expect(wrapper.props().image_url).to.equal(url);
```

Not sure why you are testing URL.

You can do

```
 expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot(); // this will cover whole image component.
```

Comment: that didn't work, but this works `expect(wrapper.props().image_url).toBe(url);`

Comment: does `toBe` is the same ?

Comment: yes. One more thing in unit testing test your code not react code. Here you have passed props it will be there no matter what. So checking for URL in expect is not good unit test. Try to use snapshot.

Comment: it works but `expect(wrapper.props().image_url).to.equal(url);` should be edited to `expect(wrapper.props().image_url).toBe(url);`

Comment: thanks for explaining about snapshot testing. When is it best to use snapshot testing besides the example i shared ?